# lisp program to calculate the sum of n numbers

Tags: lisp

```
(defun sum-n-numbers(n)(if(=n 1)
1
(+N(sum-n-numbers(-n 1)))))
```

Edit 2:`(defun sum-n-numbers(n)
        (if(=n 1)
        1
        (+N(sum-n-numbers(-n 1))
        )

        )

        )` 
The above code runs but when I type (SUM-N-NUMBERS 1 3 2) for the output,it does not work and I get errors.
I know this simple code can also be executed by the inbuild lisp function (+ 1 3 2) that automatically calculates the sum of the numbers,but I have an exam question where it is asked to calculate the sum of n numbers using the defun function.

Edit 1: This is the error that I am getting:

```
Error: Call ((LAMBDA (#:N) (DECLARE (SPECIAL:SOURCE #) (LAMBDA-NAME SUM-N-NUMBERS))                  (BLOCK #:SUM-N-NUMBERS (IF # 1 #))) 1 3 2) has the wrong number of arguments.
1 (abort) Return to level 1.
2 Return to debug level 1.
3 Return to level 0.
4 Return to top loop level 0.
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @JackManey Thanks for your response,this is the error that i am getting: `
Error: Call ((LAMBDA (#:N) (DECLARE (SPECIAL:SOURCE #) (LAMBDA-NAME SUM-N-NUMBERS)) (BLOCK #:SUM-N-NUMBERS (IF # 1 #))) 1 3 2) has the wrong number of arguments.
  1 (abort) Return to level 1.
  2 Return to debug level 1.
  3 Return to level 0.
  4 Return to top loop level 0.`

Comment: @JackManey I have edited my question so that it is easy to read the error.

Comment: now you'd need to format the Lisp function in a proper way...

Comment: (1) understand that characters you might think of as operations or punctuation in other languages can make up valid symbols in Lisp (2) separate symbols with whitespace and (3) don't abuse the fact that your Lisp reader appears to convert alpha characters to uppercase by using consistent case (4) do some reading and experimentation - this is your exam!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
(apply '+ '(1 3 2))
```

??

```
(defun sum (numbers)
  (if (null numbers)
      0
      (+ (first numbers) (sum (rest numbers)))))

(sum '(1 3 2))
```

Didn't test. I don't have a lisp interpreter at hand.

Comment: How can i change this code so that the user can input n number of arguments

Answer (score 2):

To get exactly what you want:

```
(defun sum-n-numbers (&rest nums)
    (if (null nums) 0 
        (+ (car nums) (apply #'my-sum (cdr nums)))))
```

This will take an arbitrary number of arguments and recursively compute their sum. For instance:

`(sum-n-numbers 1 2 3) => 6`

Using iteration, not recursion:

```
(defun sum-n-numbers (&rest nums)
    (loop for num in nums summing num))
```

From the user's point of view, these are the same, just a little bit different in how they work inside. And I've tested both of these to ensure they work.

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote accepts one argument and returns the sum of of numbers from 1 to the argument (note that it will never return - theoretically - and fail with a stack overflow - in practice - for negative arguments).

That function cannot accept 3 arguments you passed to it, so you got an error.